# Trojan in install-tl-windows.exe reported by Windows Defender

Tags: texlive, installing

a colleague of mine have a strange problem with the windows installer. She downloaded the install-tl-windows.exe from https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html in a fresh and clean machine running Windows 10.

The download was blocked by Edge, but she was able to allow it and complete the download. However, after the download, Windows Defender automatically erase the file and reports a "critical threat" as Trojan:Win32/Wacatac:B!ml.

Now, I had downloaded and installed the same executable like two months ago without issues and with Windows Defender on. I have tried on another pc this morning and the malware reported was indeed there. My colleague tried two other Windows machine and the results were the same.

She cannot disable the antivirus since is a work pc.

I know about false positives and in the past I had some problem during the installation. But this is the first time that the installer itself is deleted and reported as a precise Trojan by Windows Defender on a vanilla and clean installation without other antimalware software.

Since I've downloaded the same file two months ago without issues, is there a possibility the file is now infected? Can the file be whitelisted by the authors or by a communication to Windows?

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine so I cannot confirm, but if true this should be reported to the tex live infra mailing list https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live